# Given two randomly chosen natural numbers, what is the probability that the second is greater than the first?

Tags: probability

Suppose that there exists some apparatus that, when prompted, displays a random natural number (i.e. it picks an integer uniformly from the range $[1, \infty)$).

A man writes down a number generated by this apparatus, denotes it as the first number, and afterwards prompts the apparatus for another number, writes it down, and denotes it as the second number. **What is the probability that the second number will be greater than the first number?**

I think the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$, because in the general case, the probability of the second number being greater than the first given two integers selected from the range $[1, n]$ is $\frac{n - 1}{2n}$. If you take the limit of this as $n$ approaches infinity, you get $\frac{1}{2}$.

I have a friend who says that the answer is $1$, since the first number is guaranteed to be finite. He argues that if you have some finite number and then choose a random number from the set $[1, n]$, the resulting number, with probability $1$, will be greater than the originally chosen finite number.

Which one of us, if not both, is wrong? Or is the problem poorly defined and thus impossible to answer?

Comment: The first number is guaranteed to be finite, but so is the second, so... ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is **not possible** to pick an integer in the range $[1,\infty)$ in such a way that *each possible selection has equal probability*, and you have discovered one of many arguments for this impossibility.

More specifically, assume that there was such a probability distribution. If the shared probability $p$ of choosing any particular number is greater than $0$, then it must also be greater than $\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$ (that is how real numbers work). But then the *total* probability of getting one of the numbers $1$, $2$, $3,\ldots, n$ would be greater than $1$ which is absurd.

On the other hand, if $p=0$, then the probability of getting *any* natural number at all would be $0$ (which is also absurd). This is because probability distributions are required to be *countably additive*.

Therefore $p$ can neither be $0$ nor different form $0$, which is a contradiction; we must conclude that a probability distribution over the naturals where each outcome has equal probability is not possible.

Comment: can I just say? on $[a,b]$ the density is $1/(b-a)$, so if $b$ tends to infinity, the density goes to zero, so "It is not possible to pick an integer in the range $[1,\infty)$ in such a way that each possible selection has equal __non-zero__ probability."

Comment: @PatrickT: No. That qualification is not necessary because (as explained in Henning's answer) it is also not possible to pick an integer in the range $[1,\infty)$ in such a way that each possible selection has equal zero probability -- because that would give probability $0$ to pick any number at all. The fact that the density $1/(b-a)$ goes to zero does not contradict this; it never *is* zero.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Which book  contains this type of problems?

Answer (score 6):

As it was mentioned on an answer, you cannot find a way to uniformly choose a random natural number. One way to think about probabilities such as this is the concept of natural density. The natural density of a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ is defined as $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|A \cap I_{n}|}{n}$ where $I_{n} = \{1, ..., n\}$. Thus for instance, the "probability that a randomly-picked number" is prime is the density of the set of primes (which is zero). If we interpret it this way, after you pick some number $k$, you want to find the density of $\{n \in \mathbb{N}; n \neq k\}$, and this is indeed 1. Notice that, however, this concept is *not* a probability measure. It doesn't satisfy the axiom of countable additivity; indeed, for each $k$, the set $\{k\}$ has density $0$ but $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty} \{k\}$ has density $1$.