# From a set of infinite positive integers a number is picked at random. What is the probability that the integer the person picked is greater than 100.

Tags: probability

I tried this question and obtained the probability to be $1$

The total no. of outcomes are $∞$ and the no. of outcomes greater than $100$ is also $∞$ so the probability should be $∞/∞$ which turns out to be undefined

Another approach is to denote the probability of picking a positive integer greater than 100 as $P(X > 100)$. We can express this probability as a limit:

$$ P(x>100) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-100}{n} $$

As n approaches infinity, the number of positive integers greater than $100$ in the first $n$ positive integers will also approach infinity. Therefore, the limit of this ratio will be $1$.

$P(X > 100) = 1$

Hence the probability comes out to be $1$, but this is impossible. What are your thoughts on the question? (Sorry if I made any mistake as I am new to this site)

Comment: You cannot pick a value uniformly from all the positive integers.   You can do so from a finite number of integers, but there is no limiting distribution as the number of integers increases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? The linked question isn't exactly the same, but the answer there answers here too. [Given two randomly chosen natural numbers, what is the probability that the second is greater than the first?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136408/given-two-randomly-chosen-natural-numbers-what-is-the-probability-that-the-seco)

Comment: “a set of infinite positive integers” – so, the empty set? There are no infinite positive integers. Unless we are working in a nonstandard model…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infinity is not a number, but is instead a symbol of unbounded growth.

To resolve the *paradox*, re-state the problem as letting $~p(n)~$ denote the probability that the number chosen is less than or equal to $~100,~$ assuming that there are $~n~$ positive integers to choose from.

Then, you have that $~\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} p(n) = 0,~$ despite the fact that $~p(n)~$ is not equal to $~0,~$ for any finite value of $~n.$

Now, define $~q(n)~$ to be the probability of the complementary event, that among $~n~$ positive integers, the number chosen is $~> 100.~$

Then:

- $~p(n) + q(n) = 1, ~$ for all $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} q(n) = 1,~$ despite the fact that $~q(n)~$ is not equal to $~1,~$ for any finite value of $~n.$

---

Similarly, define the sequence $~\langle a_n \rangle ~$ by $~a_n = \frac{1}{n}.~$

Then $~\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0,~$ despite the fact that $~a_n \neq 0,~$ for any finite value of $~n.$

You could then define the sequence $~\langle b_n \rangle ~$ by $~b_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}.~$

Then $~\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 1~$ despite the fact that $~b_n \neq 1,~$ for any finite value of $~n.$

Comment: The OP asks for the probability of the complement event. So it might be confusing having you say the probability tends to $0$.

Comment: @SahajSatishSharma Good point.  I edited my answer accordingly.